# How to reuse view controllers in a UITabBarController in Storyboard mode with swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a UITabBarController with 3 sub views which all have the same structure, just different data or filters applied to the data. So far I've just made 3 sub views and hooked them up, but I'm repeating myself and I know this can't be the right way of doing things.

My question is how do I create 1 sub view with all it's functions and view and then reuse it just with the right filters applied. e.g.

click on the 'all data tab' > loads the view with var filter = 'all' and var order_by = 'created_date'

click on the 'completed tab' > loads the view with var filter = 'completed' and var order_by = 'completed_date'

I'm thinking it's something I can do when I prepare the segue?

Answer (score 1):

Althought there is not much context to go on in your original post here is what I think might work...

You can set a global variable in the main subview which you would like to be customizable in content based on what I understood.

```
var customizationObject = CustomFilters()
```

and for CustomFilters do something like:

```
class CustomFilters {
 var filter1: String?
 var filter2: String?
//and so on
}
```

and in the prepareForSegue you pass the object to the destination view controller to set the filters.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}
```

In the new single sub view, you check which filters are set in the viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad (depending your case) and carry on with what you want to do.

Comment: So would I still have the multiple subview in the storyboard, just load the same class?

Comment: @Designer023 well I am not sure of what your structure looks like in the storyboard, but what I suggested could lead to one parent view and one sub-view where data can be filtered based on passed filter preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found ctrl drag multiple times from tab view controller to the same tab view works.

Then in the tab controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    (self.viewControllers![0] as! DailyChartsViewController).title="Daily"
    (self.viewControllers![0] as! DailyChartsViewController).tabBarItem.image=UIImage(named: "daily")
    (self.viewControllers![0] as! DailyChartsViewController).filter = 1
    (self.viewControllers![1] as! DailyChartsViewController).title="Weekly"
    (self.viewControllers![1] as! DailyChartsViewController).tabBarItem.image=UIImage(named: "weekly")
    (self.viewControllers![1] as! DailyChartsViewController).filter = 7
}
```